# PHP form validation issue with isset() function

Tags: php

i've been learning php form validation and seem to have a confusion in the following thing

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>
    learning
  </title>
</head>

<?php
  function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<?php
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}
?>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }
}
?>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
  if(isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($gender))
  {

      $sql = "insert into learn values('$name','$email','$website','$comment','$gender')";
      if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
      {
        echo 'Entry to database successful';
      }
      else {
        echo 'Error!';
      }
  }
 ?>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
 Name: <input type="text" name="name">
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
 E-mail:
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
 Website:
 <input type="text" name="website">
 <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
 Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
 <br><br>
 Gender:
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

ok so i am trying to make a form validation with php. the page does show the error if one of the required field is empty but still enters the value in the database regardless of the error. I suspect its because of isset because if i replace the line with

```
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($gender))
```

it seems to work.

Edit 1: ok i have managed to fix the issue. thanks to the people that had helped.

Comment: You explicitly set all of those variables in your code. They are *always* set as a result.

Comment: Yeah, the variables will always be set. Verify if the `$_POST` items are set.

Comment: @JohnConde so i should unset them if the form is not filled ? or should i do !empty() ?

Comment: Check if one of the error messages is set. Or better, add the errors to an empty array and check if that array is still empty before you add the data to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this condition instead of existing

```
if(isset($name) && $name != NULL && isset($email) && $email != NULL  && isset($gender) && $gender != NULL)
```